# Issue when loading steam and some games

Tags: nvidia, graphics, steam

So when i launch steam i keep getting the following error message:

"OpenGL GLX context is not using direct rendering, which may cause performance problems.

For more information visit https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=9938-EYZB-7457"

I visit that article and it is a dead link does anyone know how i can fix this issue please tell me in steps as i am fairly new to Linux.

Also when i launch a game called "no more room in hell" i get the following error:

"could not find required OpenGl entry point "glGetError" Either your video card is unsupported or your open gl driver needs updating"

System Specs

15.6 GB of ram

Processor intel core i7-4770 CPU @ 3.40 ghz x8

Graphics Geforce GTX 760 (192 bit) PCie/SSE2

OS type 64-bit

Disk 2.0 TB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this command:

```
apt-get install libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic
```

It will install the x32 Utopic Mesa GLX binaries steam needs to run. Steam is a x32 architecture, and some x64 machines do not have this lib.